# Django custom serializer how to input ID/PK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make custom serializer work. Can't use model serializer since I will be saving data into multiple models. Here is my code:

```
class RushSerializer(serializers.Serializer):    
    keyword = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    url = serializers.URLField()  


    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        url = self.validated_data['url']
        Url1.objects.create(keyword=keyword, url=url)
```

And I input data like this:

```
nov = {'url': 'https://domain.com/'}             
nov['keyword'] = id

serializer = RushSerializer(data=nov)
```

It returns me this error:

> KeyError at /admin/keywords/kw/add/
>
> 'keyword'

Here is the model itself:

```
class Url1(models.Model):

    keyword = models.ForeignKey(KW)
    url = models.URLField()
```

What is wrong with my code? I tried pretty much [anything from here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers) but can't seem to make it work.

**EDIT: To clarify, it works if I do it with model serializer and this:**

```
class Meta:
    model = Url1       
    fields = ('keyword', 'url')
```

So problem isn't in input 100% but in serializer itself.

- If I do keyword without read_only then I get this error:

> ValueError at /admin/keywords/kw/add/ Cannot assign "104":
>   "Url1.keyword" must be a "KW" instance.

Comment: Your `keyword` has `read_only=True` which means you cannot pass data in. Anyway I suggest you use `http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield` and pass the queryset. `keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyField(queryset=Keyword.objects.all())`

Comment: Thanks man, this queryset worked perfectly !